# Replace a string in bash script using regex for both linux and AIX

Tags: regex, linux, bash, aix

I have a bash script that I copy and run on both linux and AIX servers.
This script gets a "name" parameter which represents a file name, and I need to manipulate this name via regex (the purpose is irrelevant and very hard to explain).
From the name parameter I need to take the beginning until the first "-" character that is followed by a digit, and then concat it with the last "." character until the end of the string.

For example:

```
name: abcd-efg-1.23.4567-8.jar will become: abcd-efg.jar
```

```
name: abc123-abc3.jar          will remain: abc123-abc3.jar
```

```
name: abc-890.jar              will become: abc.jar
```

I've tried several variations of:

```
name=$1
regExpr="^(.*?)-\d.*\.(.*?)$/g"
echo $name 
echo $(printf ${name} | sed -e $regExpr)
```

Also I cant use `sed -r` (seen on some examples) because AIX sed does not support the -r flag.
The last line is the problem of course; I think I need to somehow use $1 + $2 placeholders, but I can't seem to get it right.

How can I change my regex so that it does what I want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given the file:

```
abcd-efg-1.23.4567-8.jar
abc123-abc3.jar
abc-890.jar
```

This is a way to change the names you give:

```
$ sed 's/\(.\?\)-[0-9].*\(\.[a-z]*\)$/\1\2/' file
abcd-efg.jar
abc123-abc3.jar
abc.jar
```

Which is equivalent to (if you could use `-r`):

```
$ sed -r 's/(.?)-[0-9].*(\.[a-z]*)$/\1\2/' file
abcd-efg.jar
abc123-abc3.jar
abc.jar
```

- It gets everything up to `-` + `digit` and "stores" in `\1`.
- It gets from last `.` + `letters` and "stores" in `\2`.
- Finally it prints those blocks back.

Note the extension could also be fetched with the `basename` builtin or with something like `"${line##*.}".

Comment: One problem I have is when file name does not end with letters. For example: abcd-12.war.2. it gives back the entire name as is, instead of abcd.2

Comment: @Osher could you give a try to `sed 's/\(.\?\)-[0-9].*\(\.\w*\)$/\1\2/' file`? That is, to change last `[a-z]*` for `\w*` matching a word. It works to me.

Answer (score 1):

In sed, you could simply use the following.

```
#!/bin/sh
STRING=$( cat <<EOF
abcd-efg-1.23.4567-8.jar
abc123-abc3.jar
abc-890.jar
EOF
)
echo "$STRING" | sed 's/-[0-9].*\(\.[^.]\+\)$/\1/'
# abcd-efg.jar
# abc123-abc3.jar
# abc.jar
```

This matches a hyphen followed by a number and everything after and replaces with the file extension.

Or you may consider using a Perl one-liner:

```
echo "$STRING" | perl -pe 's/-\d.*(?=\.[^.]+$)//'
# abcd-efg.jar
# abc123-abc3.jar
# abc.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this:

```
perl -F'(-(?:\d)|\.)' -ane 'print "$F[0].$F[$#F]"'
```

It splits the input on any `-` followed by a digit, or any `.`. Then it prints the first field, followed by a dot, followed by the last field.

Testing it out:

```
$ cat file
abcd-efg-1.23.4567-8.jar
abc123-abc3.jar
abc-890.jar
$ perl -F'(-(?:\d)|\.)' -ane 'print "$F[0].$F[$#F]"' file
abcd-efg.jar
abc123-abc3.jar
abc.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

when a successful regex match is made, perl will capture whatever is matched in parenthesis ( .. ) as $1, $2, etc.

```
$ perl -e 'my $arg = $ARGV[0]; $arg =~ /^(.*?)-\d.*\.(.*?)$/; print "$1.$2\n"; ' abc-890.jar
abc.jar
```